# What is the expected behavior of Sharepoint workflow

Tags: workflow

If I have a list A with a workflow named "Create Item in List B" that creates an item in list B, and list B has a workflow named "Log Info" that only creates a log in the history list an is configured to start on item created, what is the expected behavior?

1. If I start the workflow "Create Item in List B" that resides in list A, the Workflow "Log Info" should start when the workflow "Create Item in List B" creates the list item in list B?
2. The workflow "Log Info" only starts if the item is created manually in list B, so when the Workflow "Create Item in List B" creates a list item in list B nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have the answer, I have 1 SharePoint 2013 instance that works like the scenario 2, but I have other 5 SharePoint instances that does not do it!!! :S it seems like is a problem of an update.

But at least now I Know that the expected behavior is 2.

Thanks for any other comment that anyone can give me about this!